# Status of children born from a yefat toar who was converted to judaism after the 30 day period

Tags: halacha, marriage, conversion-to-judaism, army-military-war, ki-teitzei

In parshat Ki Teietze it talks about the yefat torah.
If after the 30 days if he still wants to marry her, she is converted to judaism, then he can marry her.
Question: Is this conversion a regular normal conversion (which would require her assent, and, at least under the normative view of current Judaism, an extended period of education) through which
she becomes a true convert in all aspects?
Or is the conversion only partial, where she is not quite jewish?

Comment: What is a 'partial conversion'? Are there other instances of partial conversion that you are aware of that cause you to think that this might be the case here as well?

Comment: Why would you assume or question that her conversion is invalid or 'partial'? Considering the practical aspects of the 30 day cooling off period, that is to give both him & her the opportunity to observe & reflect upon the potential of their possible future relationship.

Comment: @JoelK I have seen some people refer to conversions involving the requirement of residency in the land of Israel in that sense. I agree with you that the idea seems odd.

Comment: I tried to intuit a couple of possible differences between another conversion and this one, but I'm just guessing. Feel free to roll back if I guessed wrong.

Comment: Omar yehuda omar rav, Tamar daughter of David Hamelech was also the daughter of a yefat toar.

Comment: She approached Amnon and tells Amnon to tell

Comment: David Hamelech not to restrict her from him.

Comment: So how could she believe that David Hamelech would agree to permit a marriage between brother and sister unless she believed that the daughter of a yefat toar is not jewish.

Comment: @TzviFastag Rambam explains: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Kings_and_Wars.8.8?lang=bi

Answer (score 1):

Special dispensation was given by the Torah to convert a *Yefas toar* after 30/90 days without her accepting *Mitzvos* and marrying her according to Yevamos 47b-48 (see below).

- The Rivan in Tosfos says that this Sugia and Psak is in accordance with Rabbi Eliezer that she cries for her parents and does not need to deny *avoda zara* in-order to become Jewish after those 30/90 days which would mean she is Jewish without accepting Mitzvos. In contrast, Rabbi Akiva would require rebuttal of *avoda zara* and if she hasn't broken away from *avoda zara* after a year he should let her free.
- The Rambam Melachim 8,5 however (explained by Kesef Mishne) paskens like Rabbi Akiva that she must deny avoda zara but also includes that she must accept all Mitzvos Which is not so clear from Rabbi Akiva as it could be she only need to deny avoda zara *not* accept mitzvos see Keren Orah in yevamos 47b.

Everyone agrees, Once converted of course she and her children are fully Jewish (see Kidushin 68b Bellow)
Yevamos 47-48a:

> תניא (דברים כא, יג) ובכתה את אביה ואת אמה וגו' בד"א שלא קבלה עליה אבל קבלה עליה מטבילה ומותר בה מיד ר"ש בן אלעזר אומר אע"פ שלא קבלה עליה כופה ומטבילה לשם שפחות וחוזר ומטבילה לשם שחרור ומשחררה
>   ומותר בה מיד...ירח ימים ירח שלשים יום ר"ש בן אלעזר אומר תשעים יום ירח שלשים ימים שלשים ואחר כן שלשים
>   She should cry 30 days when? if she did not accept Mitzvos i.e she is forced to convert after 30 days (by dipping in Mikva). But if she accepts Mitzvos she can convert instantly. Rabbi shimon Ben Elazar says she can be forced to immerse in Mikva to become a slave as she is captured, and then forced to immerse again to change from a slavewoman to being Jewish even without waiting or accepting Mitzvos...But the Gemora goes on to say Rabanan disagree because even a slave must accept Mitzvos and cannot forcibly convert so the only way specifically regarding Yefas Toar is the method of the Torah to wait 30 days... The Braisa says 30 days litelally, but Rabbi Shimon Ben Elazar says 90 days from the words of the Passuk: *Yerach* 30 + *Yamim* 30 + *Achar kein* 30 = 90.

Once converted after 30/90 days she and her children are fully Jewish therefore Kiddushin (betrothal)works on her, But before 30/90 days he can't do *kiddushin* on her, and her children from him are not Jewish Kidushin 68b:

> אמר קרא (דברים כא, יג) ואחר כן תבוא אליה ובעלתה וגו' מכלל דמעיקרא לא תפסי בה קידושין אשכחן דלא תפסי בה קידושין ולדה כמותה מנלן אמר קרא (דברים כא, טו) כי תהיין לאיש וילדו לו כל היכא דקרינן ביה כי תהיינה קרינן ביה וילדו לו וכל היכא דלא קרינן ביה כי תהיינה לא קרינן ביה וילדו לו

Comment: Rambam does not pasken like this ie she is never converted without her consent

Comment: @JoelK I brought down the pashut pshat like Tosfos as the Beer Miriam and Keren Orahexplains that the Rambam is not Pashut pshat otherwise whats the point in the whole process convert when shes ready! היא ק' תוס' בדף מח: הנ"ל עמש"כ ריב"ן לר"ע רק בכפירה בע"ז, דא"כ הו"ל מדעתה, **ומדעתה א"צ לכל המעשים**, ומה טעם לכל פרשה זו, ומזה הכריחו דא"צ קבלה לר"ע אבל לדעת הרמב"ם יקשה**, ושו"ר בקרן אורה שם שעמד ע"ז**